# How to test a download button in Laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, controller, download

I'm really don't understand why, my application still allow the download even after I comment out the return statement. Wired !!

My route for the download look like this

```
Route::get('catalog_downloads/{id}/download','CatalogDownloadController@file_download');
```

I have a `Download` button that trigger a modal fill with a short instructions, after they click `Ok, Got it` that when I allow them to download.

Here is my `download` button

```
<a class="black" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#instruction">
                            <b class="cool-blue">
                                Download
                            </b>

                        </a>
```

Here is my `Ok, Get it` button

```
<a href="/catalog_downloads/{{$catalog_download->id}}/download" class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-next">
                        Ok, Got it.
                        <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i>
                    </a>
```

My Download Function in my controller

```
public function file_download($id)
    {

        $catalog_download = CatalogDownload::findOrFail($id);
        $distributor      = Auth::user()->distributor()->first();
        $export_type      = $distributor->export_type()->first();
        $product_export =  $catalog_download->product_exports()->first();

        $destinationPath  = base_path().'/app/files/product_export/'. $catalog_download->id.'/'. $export_type->id.'/';
        $file_name        = $product_export->file_path;
        $pathToFile       = $destinationPath .$file_name;

        // return Response::download($pathToFile);


    }
```

Is it because of `modal` that cause all of these ? 
Did I do anything that I'm not suppose somewhere ? 
Can someone tell me what did I missed ? :(

Comment: How many user type in your application ? Does this issue also happened with others users ? OR only that one.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you hit `save` and `refresh` the page.

If possible, log out, and re-logged back in, and see if you still experience that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try testing with a INCOGNITO Window on Google Chrome or a Private Window on Firefox, so that you make sure that there is no cache, session or cookies from previous sessions.